# Pandas DataFrames: How to locate rows using index values in existing dataframe based on values from another dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of values in a dataframe called:`Modified_Index`

```
This is df: Modified_Index
    Index
0    0
1    10
2    40
3    60
4    80
5    100
```

I need to take the column 'Index' values from `Modified_Index` and search the index of `my_dataframe` for all the rows that match.

```
This is: my_dataframe
       voltage   
0      2.95020     
10      3.00436  
20      3.01263  
30      3.01858  
40      3.02402  
50      3.02894  
60      3.03363  
70      3.03792  
80      3.04210 
90      3.04596 
100     3.04978
```

A new dataframe should be created that consists of the rows that satisfy the search criteria.

The new dataframe should be:

```
This is: new_dataframe
       voltage        
10      3.00436    
40      3.02402   
60      3.03363  
80      3.04210 
100     3.04978
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the first dataframe is named "Modified_Index" and that the column in that dataframe is named "Index"...

```py
new_dataframe.loc[new_dataframe.index.isin(Modified_Index["Index"])]
```

Comment: Try the solution I posted, it should return exactly the output you are targeting.

Answer (score 2):

Try via `map()`:

```
Modified_Index['voltage']=Modified_Index['Index'].map(my_dataframe['voltage'])
```

Output of `Modified_Index`:

```
    Index   voltage
0   0       2.95020
1   10      3.00436
2   40      3.02402
3   60      3.03363
4   80      3.04210
5   100     3.04978
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loc`

```
new_dataframe=my_dataframe.loc[Modified_Index['Index'],:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using merge as well -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> d1  = {'Index' : [0,10,40,60,80,100] }
>>> d2 = {'voltage' : [random.randint(1,50) for i in range(0,10)]}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> Modified_Index = pd.DataFrame(d1)
>>> my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(d2)
>>> 
>>> my_dataframe.index = [i for i in range(0,100,10)]
>>> 
>>> my_dataframe = my_dataframe.reset_index()
>>> 
>>> Modified_Index = Modified_Index.set_index('Index')
>>> 
>>> final_df = pd.merge(my_dataframe,Modified_Index,left_on=['index'],right_on=['Index']).set_index('index')
>>> 
>>> final_df
       voltage
index         
0            1
10          22
40          33
60          50
80          19
```